# Python Pandas Dataframe Pivot with Calculation of Mean and Median and Top 20

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I am trying to create a PIVOT table in python from python with calculated columns. I have a huge amount of data running in thousands in a DataFrame.

The file has few columns which is customer alertkey and mttr

[image]

The expected output

[image]

The Output is expected to have Customer and AlertKey (Top 5 count only) wise groupby. Then against each alertKey its corresponding Mean and Median MTTR

The dataframe is created by pulling data from multiple tables of database. Now I am stuck on how to do the representation. This cannot be easily done in excel as we need to pull the records from multiple databases + median calculation in Excel Pivot is a pain. Also the process need to be automated.

```
df.groupby(['Customer','AlertKey']).AlertKey.value_counts().nlargest(20)
```

[The Excel File with Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IeZ6Jh3n79EXZA7PrnEaAufjAYyqaUF_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do I calculate the total numbers by value_counts and not try to filter by Top 20 - to keep things simple for the calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider first creating indicators for value count ranking and then run `groupby().agg()` call:

```
df['AKCount'] = df.groupby(['Customer'])['AlertKey'].transform('value_counts')
df['AKCountRank'] = df.groupby(['Customer'])['AKCount'].transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='max'))

sub = df[df['AKCountRank'] <= 20]

gdf = sub.groupby(['Customer', 'AlertKey'])['MTTR'].agg(['count','mean','median'])
```

**Data**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt ="""
Customer AlertKey MTTR
C1 C1A1 38
C1 C1A2 25
C2 C2A5 40
C1 C1A1 50
C3 C3A7 60
C3 C3A7 23
C5 C5A8 29
C3 C3A7 30
C5 C5A8 40
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")
```

**Output**

```
print(gdf)

#                    MTTR                  
#                   count       mean median
# Customer AlertKey                        
# C1       C1A1         2  44.000000   44.0
#          C1A2         1  25.000000   25.0
# C2       C2A5         1  40.000000   40.0
# C3       C3A7         3  37.666667   30.0
# C5       C5A8         2  34.500000   34.5
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response. gdf = df.groupby(['Customer', 'AlertKey']).agg(['count','mean','median'])
 doesn't provide information that count should be of AlertKey and Mean and Median should be of MTTR. We never mentioned it anywhere?? Am I understanding it incorrectly? I understanding Top 20 will be difficult to achieve for AlertKey Count in the same formula ?and has to be manually done ?

Comment: Without specifying a numeric field, `agg` runs on all numeric columns of a dataframe. Hence, here would be for *MTTR*. And *count* would be the group count. I almost asked what you mean by Top 5 / Top 20? Can you explain further in your question? This answer does reproduce your Excel screenshot!

Comment: I cannot open GDrive links for security. Can you post sample rows in body of question?

Comment: The original dataset has more number of AlertKey than I can manage in the screenshot per customer. For e.g a customer will have 100s of alertkey in the data file. Now if I calculate and groupby all the alertkey it will become almost unreadable. So we just need to have TOP 20 counts of AlertKey per customer instead of all AlertKey for the customer.

Comment: Sorry for my clumsy questions. But to find the top 20 I was trying the below

df.groupby(['Customer','AlertKey']).AlertKey.value_counts().nlargest(20)

Comment: See update where you create indicators for the *AlertKey* value rank and then subset entire dataframe into a, *sub* before `groupby`.

Comment: Wow you are amazing - i had no clue how you managed that :-) thank you very much for your time and efforts - really appreciate it. I am sure others will benefit from this :)

Comment: Haha! No problem. Glad to help and happy coding!